# If $f$ is entire and $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, what does this imply about $f$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is entire and that $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.
Show $$|f^{(n)}(0)| \leq 1/R^n$$
for all positive integers $n$. What does this say about $f$?

This is what I tried:

Suppose $f$ is entire. Then $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{k!}z^k$.

Considering the contour $\Gamma$, the circle of radius $R$ at the origin and Cauchy-Integral formula,
$$\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz= f^{(n)}(0) \\ \implies |f^{(n)}(0)| = \frac{n!}{2\pi}\left|\int_{\Gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz\right|\\ \leq \frac{n!}{2\pi} \times 2\pi R \times \frac{1}{R^{n+1}} \\ = \frac{n!}{R^n}.$$
I don't see how they have the numerator as $1$.

So what happens now? I think I can take $R\rightarrow \infty$, so $f^{(n)}(0)= 0$ **provided** that $R$ is large, **and** $n$ doesn't grow large as well (but it does?) 
So the series has every term vanish except the constant term.

Comment: Isn't a bounded and entire function constant? That's what Liouville's theorem says, right?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure how to use the process that the original question wanted me to use instead, or rather, I don't understand specifically the paragraph at the end.

Comment: I think there's a mistake in the question. The Taylor coefficients satisfy $a_n\leq 1/R^n$, but $f^{(n)}(0)$ has to have the $n!$ term in it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)

Comment: There are some errors in your post and reasoning. Notice that $R$ is not defined in your post. Later you take the contour $\Gamma$ to be a circle of radius $1$, yet you use $R$ as the radius later. You cannot get rid of the factorial $n!$, however this is not needed. See my answer below for clarification.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. It doesn't say what $R$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is entire and that $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.   We have to show that  $$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}_0:\forall \varepsilon>0: |f^{(n)}(0)| < \varepsilon.$$

So choose $n\in \mathbb{N}_0$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Fix a contour $\Gamma$ which is a circle of radius $R$ (The value $R$ can still be varied). Then by Cauchy's formula

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz&=& f^{(n)}(0)\\
|f^{(n)}(0)|& = & |\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz|\\
&\leq& \frac{n!}{2\pi }\int_{\Gamma} |\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}|dz\\
&\leq& \frac{n!}{2\pi }\int_{\Gamma} |\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}|dz\\
&=& \frac{n!}{2\pi }\cdot 2\pi R\cdot \frac{1}{R^{n+1}}\\
&=&\frac{n!}{R^n }.\\
\end{eqnarray}

Hence $|f^{(n)}(0)|\leq \frac{n!}{R^n}$. But we can choose $R$ as large as we want, hence taking $R$ large enough yields $|f^{(n)}(0)|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: We have $e^R=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{R^n}{n!}$ and this series converges.  So, $\frac{R^n}{n!}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.  So, $\frac{n!}{R^n}\to \infty$.  How can $\frac{n!}{R^n}$ be made small in this case?

Comment: @S.Venkataraman: Because $n$ is fixed. For every $n$, we can still choose $R$.

Comment: @S.Venkataraman: You are taking this limit: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}$, I am taking this one: $\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}$. There is a huge difference.

Comment: Ok.  Understood. But, the problem is not properly framed. What is $R$? How is it related to $n$ or $f$?

Comment: @ Mathematician. OK.  Understood. I was wrong. But, the problem is not properly framed. What is $R$? How is it related to $n$ or $f$? The answer is not what the OP wants. The OP wants $\left\vert f^{(n)}(0)\right\vert \leq \frac{1}{R^n}$, not $\left\vert f^{(0)}\right\vert<\epsilon$. The OP wants a specific relation. Of course, by Liouville's theorem, $f^{(n)}(z)=0$, for $n\geq 1$, so we don't even need the above argument to show that $f^{(n)}(z)=0$ if that is want the OP wants to prove ultimately.

Comment: @S.Venkataraman: I agree and understand what you are saying. I believe the OP basically wants to prove Liouville's theorem based on his reaction on my first comment.